# javascript get text option instead value

Tags: javascript

i am trying to get the value of an option with the value set.
via javascript though I get the text instead of the value
is there something i'm doing wrong?

```
<div id="scheda">
    <form name="scheda">
        <fieldset class="gruppo">
          <fieldset class="row"><label>Tipologia contratto</label>
                <select name="contratto" id="contratto" class="select">
                    <option value="0">--</option>
                    <option value="1">Contratto 1/2 giorni</option>
                    <option value="2">Contratto 3 giorni</option>
                    <option value="3">Contratto 4 giorni</option>
                    <option value="4">Contratto 5 giorni</option>
                    <option value="5">Non in attività</option>
                </select>
            </fieldset>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

this is the js code

```
var tipocontratto = document.scheda.contratto.value;
```

the console log instead of giving me the value set gives me the text of the option

Answer (score 0):

```js
function getValue() {
   console.log(window.contratto.value)
}
```

```html
<div id="scheda">
  <form name="scheda">
      <fieldset class="gruppo">
        <fieldset class="row"><label>Tipologia contratto</label>
              <select name="contratto" id="contratto" class="select">
                  <option value="0">--</option>
                  <option value="1">Contratto 1/2 giorni</option>
                  <option value="2">Contratto 3 giorni</option>
                  <option value="3">Contratto 4 giorni</option>
                  <option value="4">Contratto 5 giorni</option>
                  <option value="5">Non in attività</option>
              </select>
          </fieldset>
      </fieldset>
  </form>
  <button onCLick="getValue()">Get Value</button>
</div>
```

Since `contratto` is an `id` you can access it directly via the `window` object.

So `window.contratto.value` should do the trick.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value') from the console with this method I still don't see the value

Comment: Can you update your snippet with some more info, when do you run the javascript code for example ?

Answer (score 0):

i found the problem.

the select is repeated further down to retrieve the data of a user that has already been saved, in that select the values ​​inside the options were missing.

```
<fieldset class="row"><label>Tipologia contratto</label>
   <select name="contratto" class="select">
      <option <?php  if($ut->tipo_contratto=="0"){?> selected="selected" <?php  }?> >--</option>
      <option <?php  if($ut->tipo_contratto=="1"){?> selected="selected" <?php  }?> >Contratto 1-2 giorni</option>
      <option <?php  if($ut->tipo_contratto=="2"){?> selected="selected" <?php  }?> >Contratto 3 giorni</option>
      <option <?php  if($ut->tipo_contratto=="3"){?> selected="selected" <?php  }?> >Contratto 4 giorni</option>
      <option <?php  if($ut->tipo_contratto=="4"){?> selected="selected" <?php  }?> >Contratto 5 giorni</option>
      <option <?php  if($ut->tipo_contratto=="5"){?> selected="selected" <?php  }?> >Non in attivita</option>
    </select>
</fieldset>
```

replaced with

```
<fieldset class="row"><label>Tipologia contratto</label>
   <select name="contratto" class="select">
      <option value="0" <?php  if($ut->tipo_contratto=="0"){?> selected="selected" <?php  }?> >--</option>
      <option value="1" <?php  if($ut->tipo_contratto=="1"){?> selected="selected" <?php  }?> >Contratto 1-2 giorni</option>
      <option value="2" <?php  if($ut->tipo_contratto=="2"){?> selected="selected" <?php  }?> >Contratto 3 giorni</option>
      <option value="3" <?php  if($ut->tipo_contratto=="3"){?> selected="selected" <?php  }?> >Contratto 4 giorni</option>
      <option value="4" <?php  if($ut->tipo_contratto=="4"){?> selected="selected" <?php  }?> >Contratto 5 giorni</option>
      <option value="5" <?php  if($ut->tipo_contratto=="5"){?> selected="selected" <?php  }?> >Non in attivita</option>
    </select>
</fieldset>
```